# Python - convert function parameter input to hex

Tags: python, string, hex, decimal

I have a python function called read_memory that has one parameter that is called addr. I want to implement a way to convert the addr to HEX value. It sounds simple but the user can enter either a string/int in the parameter:

```
read_memory(0x106940)
read_memory('0x106940')
read_memory(106940)    #this is an int
read_memory('106940')
```

The result should all be 0x106940. I have the following code but it does not work as expected:

```
def read_memory(addr):
    hex_addr = str(addr)
    if('0x' not in hex_addr):
        hex_addr = '0x' + hex_addr
    return hex_addr
```

The results are:

```
read_memory(0x106940) -> 0x1075520
read_memory('0x106940') -> 0x106940
read_memory(106940) -> 0x106940
read_memory('106940') -> 0x106940
```

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Sisyphus comes to mind when reading this...

Comment: Why should all results be identical?

Comment: note that `0x106940` is also an `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't think it is such a great idea to have your function accept `int
>   in base 10` and `int in base 16` indiscriminately; this will hurt you
>   down the road. The following treats proposal treats the input as it is, 
>   instead of "as it should be".

You could use a try except block to control the flow:

```
def read_memory(addr):
    try:
        return hex(addr)
    except TypeError:
        str_addr = str(addr)
        if('0x' != str_addr[:2]):
            hex_addr = '0x' + str_addr
        else:
            hex_addr = str_addr
        return hex_addr

print(read_memory(0x106940))     # a hex  (int base 16)
print(read_memory('0x106940'))   # a string representing a hex
print(read_memory(106940))       # an integer  (int base 10)
print(read_memory('106940'))     # a string representing a hex
```

#### The results are:

```
0x106940
0x106940
0x1a1bc        # <-- this is the hex value of integer 106940 
0x106940
```